# How can I install jquery 1.11.3 in Grails 2.4?

Tags: jquery, grails

I have this line in the plugins section in **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
```

which is the last version available in the repositories:

https://grails.org/plugin/jquery

But I need the version 1.11.3, and if I try to install it with

```
grails install-plugin
```

I receive a warning indicating that I should be using the plugins section in BuildConfig.groovy to install the plugin, which is limited to the 1.11.1 version.

How can I install it?

Would it be too dumb copying and pasting the code of **jquery-1.11.3.min.js** in the file **jquery-1.11.1.min.js**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I no longer use the jQuery Grails plugin. I prefer this approach:

ApplicationResources.groovy

```
modules = {
    jQuery1113 {
        resource "lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
    }

    app {
        dependsOn "bootstrap3", "angularJs", "jQuery1113"
    }
}
```

Then in gsp:

```
<r:require module="jQuery1113"/>
```

or

```
<r:require module="app"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to grails jquery plugin documentation you can specify the jquery version in config.groovy like following.

```
jquery {
    sources = 'jquery' // Holds the value where to store jQuery-js files /web-app/js/
    version = '1.4.1' // The jQuery version in use
}
```

https://grails.org/plugin/jquery
is this not working for you?